# How to protect my app ui to change when i changed my app language programatically?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm developing a app in two languages English and Arabic. and for this, I have a button in my app to change the language programmatically. I'm able to change it by click on a button but when I change it English to Arabic then my UI also changed left to right, but I want to remain my UI same for both. how Can I do it?
I'm changing the language using this method
 private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {

```
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    configuration.locale = locale;

    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

    return context;
}
```

and it works, but ui reflected.

Comment: so you want to change the resources only not the layout, right ?

Comment: yes, i want only text not ui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you dont want RTL support in your app? Try android:supportsRtl="false" in your menifest.

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="false"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
...
</application>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `android:supportsRtl="false"` to the **manifest.xml** file, inside the `<application>` tag. This will fix your UI orientation, but might negatively affect your text orientation as right-to-left is necessary in Arabic.

Another solution is to add `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` inside your activities.